# Will applying Path compression to Union Find always results in a flat tree, If so, Why?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, union-find

The below images show a Union find Problem solved by rank with path compression. If you don't understand my handwriting then read the description below to understand what I have done.

**Description:**

First I have done Union of 1 and 2. Second, Union(3,4). Third Union(5,6) and so on by comparing their ranks while also doing path compression when finding the representative element of the tree whose union is to be done.

**My Doubt:**

My doubt is, If you look at the final tree in the image, you'll see a tree completely flat ( flat means I meant the tree's depth ). Will path compression always result in a flat tree no matter how many elements are present?
And Also how can we find the Union_find's time complexity with path compression?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to build inverse-trees of unlimited depth.  E.g., if you happen to always choose the roots as your `Union()` arguments, then no paths will be compressed, and you can build your tree as tall as you like.

If (as your written notes suggest) you use rank to choose the root resulting from your union, then your trees will be balanced, so you will need `Ω(2^n)` operations to generate a tree of depth `n`.  (Specifically:  to build a tree of of depth `n`, first build two trees of depth `n-1` and take the `Union()` of their roots.)

The amortized time complexity of union-find with rank-matching and path compression is known to be `O(inverse_ackermann)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I would like to know one thing, How did you say that I need O(2^n) operation to generate a tree of depth n

Comment: A perfectly balanced binary tree of depth `n` has `2^n-1` nodes and `2^n-2` links; rank-matching forces your trees to be approximately balanced, thus `O(2^n)`.  If each operation creates one link, you will need that many operations.

Comment: Actually, I should have said you will need `&Omega;(2^n)` operations to generate a tree of depth `n` -- I will try and fix that.

Comment: I have also added a procedure to to construct a tree of depth n